# What is wrong with my Python3.10.5 or PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I cannot run any code whenever I am trying to run my code this Messages always pops up, I already de-installed and re-installed python and PyCharm and it did not fix it:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lucia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 11, in execfile
    stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable
  File "C:\Users\lucia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tokenize.py", line 394, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/lucia/PycharmProjects/BSRN_Project_22'
```

Comment: Have you tried running the script as administrator?

Comment: Since it is in the Users directory, running as admin seems like a bad idea. It could work to only debug issues, not to solve the problem.